# ajax json parsing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
json : {"status" : 0, "err_msg": "", "list":[{"id":100, "username":"la", num:"0100000"}]}

<script>
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
    url : "myAPI",
    data: "{ \"offset\" : 0, \"limit\" : 10 }",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(json) {
    var message_list = json.list;
    var list_count = message_list.length;
    $.each(list_count, function() {
        var message_id = message_list.id;
        var message_username = message_list.username;
        var message_num = message_list.num;

        var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>"+message_id+"</td>";
        html += "<td>"+message_username+"</td>";
        html += "<td>"+message_num+"</td>";
        html += "</tr>";

        $("#tablebody").append(html);
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("에러");
    }
});
</script>
```

please fix an error I want go success:(

Comment: are you sure you are getting json type as reponse?the only way you wont go to success is when you are not returning a valid json from the url

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting as well.

Answer (score 0):

The json should look like this:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "err_msg": "",
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "username": "la",
            "num": "0100000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the num has also double quotes
If you defined dataType json then you are waiting from server API a json type object if you get a parse error make sure you are getting an object json from API.

If the json returned is the one comming from server it should be a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$.each` not properly.

```
var message_list = json.list; // array
var list_count = message_list.length; // length 
$.each(list_count, function() { // why do you call `$.each(length)`?
    var message_id = message_list.id; // why do you call array.id?
    var message_username = message_list.username;
    var message_num = message_list.num;

    var html = "<tr>";
    html += "<td>"+message_id+"</td>";
    html += "<td>"+message_username+"</td>";
    html += "<td>"+message_num+"</td>";
    html += "</tr>";

        $("#tablebody").append(html);
        });
    }
```

It should be:

```
var message_list = json.list; // array

$.each(message_list, function() { // $.each(array)
    var message_id = this.id; // "this" context - is an item
    var message_username = this.username;
    var message_num = this.num;

    var html = "<tr>";
    html += "<td>"+message_id+"</td>";
    html += "<td>"+message_username+"</td>";
    html += "<td>"+message_num+"</td>";
    html += "</tr>";

    $("#tablebody").append(html);
});
```